# alter public database link to private in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dblink

I have a database link in my database which is created as public as below.

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK dblink_name CONNECT TO usernane USING 'tag';
```

I have a requirement to convert it to a **PRIVATE** database link.
Is there any way to ALTER it without recreating it?

Many thanks.

Comment: A note about private links - you cannot create a private database link in a schema besides your own, and only the owner of a private database link can drop it (not even SYS can drop private database links created/owned by other schemas).  Some Oracle docs reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8011.htm#SQLRF01514).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You'll need to create a new private database link.  Public database links (and synonyms) are owned by a different user than private database links (and synonyms) and you can't alter an object to change the owner.